# Django Rest Framework - Object of type <> is not Json seralizable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new to django rest framework and need some help.

I have ApiView:

```
class SomeApiView(APIView):
   def get_url(self, some_id):
     return generate_url(Choices.BOOK, some_id)

   def get(self,request):
     id = request.query_params.get("some_id")
     result_url = self.get_url(id)
     return Response({'result_url': result_url})
```

here when sending request I get next error:

```
Object of type Choices is not Json serializable.
```

Choices looks like this:

```
class Choices(Enum):
  BOOK="book"
  MOVIE="movie"
  GAME="game"
```

how can I fix this error? Thank you in advance

Comment: How have you defined the generate_url function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `Choice` is not able to be converted to json. Your ideal outcome is `{'result_url': 'book'}` for example (I assume), but right now it's `{'result_url': Choice}` which cannot be converted to json.

My point is that instead of `Choice` you need to return something json serializable (like a string). My best guess is that you need `{'result_url': result_url.value}`, but I do not know if this will work as I do not know the rest of your code.

Comment: Is it an option to use SerializerMethodField for generating result url?

Comment: I don't know how your serializer looks like so i could not say.